# Having trouble in simulating data on verilog

Tags: verilog, xilinx

I made new question sheet for more details.
I'm designing some codes of data bus-system by using ideal SRAM and CPU. I want to write memory mem[0] -> IR, and read memory IR -> mem[1], and finally write memory mem[1] -> DR.

I think that dumping data on `mem` is not normal now because memory and `dout` value is coming out ZZZZ all times. Data on SRAMs aren't moving well. How can I fix this?

```
module sram(addr,clk,din,dout,we);

parameter addr_width = 12, word_depth = 4096, word_width = 16;

input clk,we;
input [addr_width-1:0] addr;
input [word_width-1:0] din;
output [word_width-1:0] dout;


reg [word_width-1:0]mem[0:word_depth-1];
reg [word_width-1:0] dout;

always @(posedge clk) begin
    if(!we)
        mem[addr] <= din[word_width-1:0];
    end

always @(posedge clk) begin

     dout[word_width-1:0] <= mem[addr];
 end

endmodule




module cpu(clk,load,reset,select,ir,dr,ac,ar,pc,addr,we);

input clk,reset;
input [1:0]select;
input [1:0]load;

output reg[15:0] ir,dr,ac;
output reg[11:0] ar,pc;

input we;
input [11:0] addr;

reg[15:0] din;
wire[15:0] dout;

sram sram(addr,clk,din,dout,we);

always @ (posedge clk or negedge reset) begin
    if(!reset) begin
        ar <= 12'b0;  ir <= 16'b0;  pc <= 12'b0;  dr <= 16'b0;  ac <= 16'b0;
    end

    if(select==2'b01 && load==2'b01 && we==1) //read
        ir[15:0] <= dout[15:0];
    else if(select==2'b11 && load==2'b10 && we==0) //write
        din[15:0] <= ir[15:0];
    else if(select==2'b10 && load==2'b11 && we==1) //read
        dr[15:0] <= dout[15:0];
    end

endmodule




module tb_cpu();
parameter addr_width = 12, word_depth = 4096, word_width = 16;

reg clk,reset,we;
reg [1:0]select;
reg [1:0]load;
reg [addr_width-1:0] addr;
wire [word_width-1:0] ir,dr,ac;
wire [word_width-5:0] ar,pc;
integer file_pointer;
integer file_pointer2;

wire [word_width-1:0]mem[0:word_depth-1];
wire [word_width-1:0] dout;

cpu cpu(clk,load,reset,select,ir,dr,ac,ar,pc,addr,we);

always #5 clk = ~clk;

initial begin
    clk = 0; we = 0; reset = 1;
    #2 reset = 0; 
    #2 reset = 1;

    file_pointer = $fopen("reg.dat");
    file_pointer2 = $fopen("memory.dat");

    $readmemb("sram.dat", tb_cpu.cpu.sram.mem);

    #10 select = 2'b01; load = 2'b01; we = 1; addr = 12'b000000000000; //cycle 1
    #10 select = 2'b11; load = 2'b10; we = 0; addr = 12'b000000000001; //cycle 2
    #10 select = 2'b10; load = 2'b11; we = 1; addr = 12'b000000000001; //cycle 3

    $fdisplay(file_pointer, "AR = %b", tb_cpu.cpu.ar);
    $fdisplay(file_pointer, "IR = %b", tb_cpu.cpu.ir);
    $fdisplay(file_pointer, "PC = %b", tb_cpu.cpu.pc);
    $fdisplay(file_pointer, "DR = %b", tb_cpu.cpu.dr);
    $fdisplay(file_pointer, "AC = %b", tb_cpu.cpu.ac);

    $fdisplay(file_pointer2, "mem[0000 0000 0000] = %b",tb_cpu.cpu.sram.mem[000000000000]);
    $fdisplay(file_pointer2, "mem[0000 0000 0001] = %b",tb_cpu.cpu.sram.mem[000000000001]);
    $fdisplay(file_pointer2, "mem[0000 0000 0010] = %b",tb_cpu.cpu.sram.mem[000000000010]);

     $fclose(file_pointer);
     $fclose(file_pointer2);

    #10 $finish;
end    
endmodule
```

Comment: how do you know about *dout*? you do not print its value.  Since 'mem' is reg, it should not come as zzzz, most likely as 'xxxx'. This probably is a result of a bad 'sram.dat' file.

Comment: @Serge I dumped SRAM by sram.dat as
0000000000001111
0000000000001110
0000000000001100

Is this bad file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason is that you need 2 clock cycles to propagate `mem->dout->ir`.

In your case sram reads `dout` at posedge clk. At the same posedge you push its value into `ir`. But hardware and simulation push the old value of `dout` which was `xxx...`. You need to give it more time to settle down. So, if you use `#20` instead of `#10` in your test bench, you should see different results.

Comment: Oh I understood, there was no time to push the new value. I thought this RTL is ideal so don't need to give it more time to settle down.